# Doctrine select entity without related entities Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity, Seller which has mapped entities to it, Clients. I want to select my Seller to update it's fields, however it does 260 queries (looking through queries I see that it selects all it's Clients and Clients other mapped entities).

I need only Seller object, for best performance. Any ideas how I would optimize my query?

I get my Seller as follows: `return $this->findOneBy(array('hash' => $hash));`

I found what the problem is, when I create my form I do the following

```
$builder->add('url')
                    ->add('theme', null, array('error_bubbling' => true))
                    ->add('demo_link_client', 'entity', array(
                            'required' => false,

                            'class' => 'MyProject\MyBundle\Entity\Client',
                            'property' => 'email',
                            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')->where('c.seller = 1');
                            },
                            'label' => 'Demo Data Set',
                            'empty_value' => 'Auto select demo data',
                            'empty_data'  => null))
```

Instead of hitting the database once Doctrine does it for each Client Entity it finds.

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Can you show the mapping of your entities ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do that.
Querying database for clients (to display their Name in select box...) and having:

```
'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')->where('c.seller = 1');
                        },
```

inside the FormType, Doctrine queries database for each one of clients found in "where" statement. This is a very bad idea, however it is hard to notice if you have only 6-10 rows coming back.

**Improvement:**

I should get my data in Controller and pass it to FormType:

```
$demo_data = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyProjectMyBundle:Client')->findBy(array('seller' => 1));
//pass data to FormType
$form = $this->createForm(new SellerType(),$seller, array('demo_data' => $demo_data));
```

In FormType:

```
 $demo = $options['demo_data'];

 ->add('demo_link_client','entity',array(
                    'required'  => false,
                    'class' => 'MyProject\MyBundle\Entity\Client',
                    'property'  => 'email',
                    'data'      => $demo,
                    'label' => 'Demo Data Set',
                    'empty_value' => 'Auto select demo data',
                    'empty_data'  => null))
```

Thanks.